# Transferring multiple data from array into different rows of a Database

Tags: arrays, database, sorting

Basically, for a school project we have to sort a database using bubble sort (very inefficient i know). So far i have achieved this by creating an array from the database and then sorting that array. The issue i now have is figuring out a way to put this sorted array back into the database for user viewing.

This is the code i have so far...

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.Patient_ListingDataSet.Tables(0)

    '------  Creating Name Array  ------'
    listName.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listName.DisplayMember = "pName"
    Dim Length As Integer = Me.listName.Items.Count - 1

    i = 0
    ReDim arrName(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrName(i) = $"{(row("pName"))}"
        i += 1
    Next


    '-----  Bubble sorting Names (Z - A) -----'

        Dim Length As Integer = Me.listName.Items.Count - 1
        Dim swapped As Boolean = True
        Dim bubbleTempName As String

        While swapped = True
            swapped = False
            For Pass = 1 To Length
                For i = 0 To Length - 1
                    If arrName(i) < arrName(i + 1) Then
                        bubbleTempName = arrName(i)
                        arrName(i) = arrName(i + 1)
                        arrName(i + 1) = bubbleTempName
                        swapped = True
                    End If
                Next i
            Next Pass
        End While
```

I just cant figure out how to get that now sorted array, back into the database. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to use a for loop and then add a new row until all the values were added in. And in order to get all columns filled i had to create an array for each column, sort each one, and then finally add the sorted array to it's appropriate column again.

Here's all the code: 
      Dim dt As DataTable = Me.Patient_ListingDataSet.Tables(0) 'defines the used datatable

```
    '------  Creating Name Array  ------'

    listName.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listName.DisplayMember = "pName"

    Dim Length As Integer = Me.listName.Items.Count - 1

    i = 0
    ReDim arrName(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrName(i) = $"{(row("pName"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '------  Creating Age Array  ------'

    listAge.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listAge.DisplayMember = "pAge"

    i = 0
    ReDim arrAge(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrAge(i) = $"{(row("pAge"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '------  Creating Weight Array  ------'

    listWeight.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listWeight.DisplayMember = "pWeight"

    i = 0
    ReDim arrWeight(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrWeight(i) = $"{(row("pWeight"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '------  Creating Height Array  ------'

    listHeight.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listHeight.DisplayMember = "pHeight"

    i = 0
    ReDim arrHeight(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrHeight(i) = $"{(row("pHeight"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '------  Creating BMI Array  ------'

    listBMI.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listBMI.DisplayMember = "pBMI"

    i = 0
    ReDim arrBMI(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrBMI(i) = $"{(row("BMI"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '------  Creating BMI Array  ------'

    listBMIClass.DataSource = Me.PatientListingBindingSource
    listBMIClass.DisplayMember = "BMIClass"

    i = 0
    ReDim arrBMIClass(Length)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        arrBMIClass(i) = $"{(row("BMIClass"))}"
        i += 1
    Next

    '-----  Bubble sorting by Age (High - Low) -----'

    'If the current index in Name array is smaller than the next index, the index will swap. Largest index will 'bubble' to the top
    While swapped = True
        swapped = False
        For Pass = 1 To Length
            For i = 0 To Length - 1
                If arrName(i) > arrName(i + 1) Then

                    'Swapping the same index in the Name array
                    TempName = arrName(i)
                    arrName(i) = arrName(i + 1)
                    arrName(i + 1) = TempName

                    'Swapping the same index in the Age array
                    TempAge = arrAge(i)
                    arrAge(i) = arrAge(i + 1)
                    arrAge(i + 1) = TempAge

                    'Swapping the same index in the Weight array
                    TempWeight = arrWeight(i)
                    arrWeight(i) = arrWeight(i + 1)
                    arrWeight(i + 1) = TempWeight

                    'Swapping the same index in the Height array
                    TempHeight = arrHeight(i)
                    arrHeight(i) = arrHeight(i + 1)
                    arrHeight(i + 1) = TempHeight

                    'Swapping the same index in the BMI array
                    TempBMI = arrBMI(i)
                    arrBMI(i) = arrBMI(i + 1)
                    arrBMI(i + 1) = TempBMI

                    'Swapping the same index in the BMIClass array
                    TempBMIClass = arrBMIClass(i)
                    arrBMIClass(i) = arrBMIClass(i + 1)
                    arrBMIClass(i + 1) = TempBMIClass

                    swapped = True
                End If
            Next i
        Next Pass
    End While

    Patient_ListingDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Clear() 'Clears table for now sorted data

    For Me.i = 0 To Length 'event occurs until the all indexes are added

        'Creats a new row for each index being addad
        Dim newRow As Patient_ListingDataSet.Patient_ListingRow
        newRow = Me.Patient_ListingDataSet.Patient_Listing.NewRow()

        'ensures arrays are added into corresponing columns of datatable
        newRow.pName = arrName(i)
        newRow.pAge = arrAge(i)
        newRow.pWeight = arrWeight(i)
        newRow.pHeight = arrHeight(i)
        newRow.BMI = arrBMI(i)
        newRow.BMIClass = arrBMIClass(i)

        'the arrays are added to the created row
        Me.Patient_ListingDataSet.Patient_Listing.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Next
End Sub
```